# Write python code that changes all the repeated characters in string to "@" except the first occurence of that character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I want to make a python code that changes the second occurrence of each character to "@" without changing the first occurrence like:

> "Python is good prototyping language" to "Python is g@@d @r@@@@@@ la@@u@@e"

I have written the following code but it does'nt work

```
text = input ( "please enter some text ")
for i in range(len(text)):
    abc = text[i]
    text.replace(abc,"@")
print(text)
```

Please tell me how to make it work
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = 'Python is good prototyping language'
seen = []
new_s = ''
for i in s:
   if i not in seen:
       new_s += i
       seen.append(i)
   else:
       if i != ' ':
           new_s += "@"
       else:
           new_s += ' '
```

Output:

```
'Python is g@@d pr@@@@@@@@@ la@@u@@e'
```

Even sorter solution:

```
new_s = ''.join('@' if a in s[:i] and a != ' ' else a for i, a in enumerate(s))
```

Output:

```
'Python is g@@d pr@@@@@@@@@ la@@u@@e'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
text = input("please enter some text ")
l, seen = [], set()
for c in text:
    if c in seen and c != ' ':
        l.append("@")
    else:
        l.append(c)
        seen.add(c)
print(''.join(l))
```

You could also check directly in the list for previous chars, but a set has a better contains-check. Similarly, you could directly assemble a string, but list's `append` has better performance than an immutable string's `+=`.

Simpler, but less performant, at least for long input:

```
text = input("please enter some text ")
s = ''
for c in text:
    s += c if c not in s or c == ' ' else '@'
print(s)
```

Comment: yes, doubly less performant: 1) changes string and 2) no `set`. Good answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yup, yet I can imagine you need a few characters in the input to offset the overhead of the more complex data structures.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not claiming this is good, only that it's an off-beat alternative.

```
>>> s = "Python is good prototyping language"
>>> class Replacer(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         self[key]='@'
...         return key
... 
>>> replacer = Replacer()
>>> ''.join([replacer[c] for c in s])
'Python is@g@@d@pr@@@@@@@@@@la@@u@@e'
```